# determine maximum value of slider with selenium

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have java based selenium code that does some functional tests of a website. In testing the results of a search I start to set the first and last year with the slider, so that I have predictable results.

I do this by moving the minhandle and the maxhandle with the proper interval. This interval I calculate by first determining the width of year in the slider (width slider / number of intervals). This works well, but, it works based on the *current* number of intervals. As soon as the builders of the site make more intervals (now it is from 2002 - 2020, making 18 intervals, but that will inevitably change in the future), the code will do wrong adjustments.

I do not know how to easily determine the max value of the slider. I found this code using google (based on *getAttribute*()), but *sm* gets the value *null*.

```
  WebElement slider = getDriver().findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id = 'slider-facetapi-facet-apachesolrsolr-block-created']"));
  String sm = slider.getAttribute("max");
```

The other solution I could think of is moving the max handle by the width of the slider, which will move it to its max position and then looking what its value is. But I only want to consider that if there is no easier solution that does not require an extra browser action.

thanks for any ideas.

the html of the slider looks like this:

```
<div id="slider-facetapi-facet-apachesolrsolr-block-created">
    <span class="facetapi-slider-min" style="margin-left: 146px;">2011</span>
    <div class="facetapi-slider" aria-disabled="false">
       <div class="ui-slider-range" style="left: 50%; width: 22.2222%;"></div><a class="ui-slider-handle ui-state-default ui-corner-all handle-min" href="#" style="left: 50%;"></a><a class="ui-slider-handle ui-state-default ui-corner-all handle-max" href="#" style="left: 72.2222%;"></a>
    </div>
    <span class="facetapi-slider-max" style="float: right; margin-right: 79.7778px;">2015</span>
</div>
```

And the slider itself looks like this:

[image: slider]

Comment: Your element doesn't have `max` attribute, it's causes return ***null***, maybe you need `slider.getSize().getHeight();` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to get this working, I changed my plan. I hope someone can benefit from this.

I have used another strategy to be independent of the min and max of the slider.
I determined the offset to move a handle by first calculating the length of a year and using that intervalwidth. I computed the intervalwidth by calculating `(sliderwidth / (slidermax - slidermin))`

But since I have not found a way to determine these two, I calculated the yearintervalwidth by using the width of the interval between the two handles:
`((max handle position - min handle position) / (max handle year - min handle year))`, yielding approximately the same value. This wil still work if the sliders range is changed at a new release. The years corresponding to the handle positions I determine by getting the text value.
In code:

```
int minJaar = 2011;     // wanted new min year of slider
int maxJaar = 2016;     // wanted new max year of slider

WebElement slider = getDriver().findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id = 'slider-facetapi-facet-apachesolrsolr-block-created']"));

WebElement minhandle = slider.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains (@class, 'handle-min')]"));
WebElement maxhandle = slider.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains (@class, 'handle-max')]"));
int startminpos = minhandle.getLocation().getX();
int startmaxpos = maxhandle.getLocation().getX();
int sliderWidth = slider.getSize().getWidth();

// determine the years of the handles of the slider
int sliderMin = Integer.parseInt(slider.findElement(
    By.xpath( "//span[ contains(@class, 'slider-min')]")).getText());
int sliderMax = Integer.parseInt (slider.findElement(
    By.xpath( "//span[ contains(@class, 'slider-max')]")).getText());

 // fall back for the case the handles are on the same year 
 double rangewidth = slider.getSize().getWidth() / 18.0;
 if (sliderMax != sliderMin)
 {   // use positions of handle to calculate handle delta per year
    rangewidth = (startmaxpos - startminpos) / (sliderMax - sliderMin);
 }

// move lower handle
Actions SliderAction = new Actions(getDriver());
SliderAction.clickAndHold(minhandle).moveByOffset(-(int)((sliderMin - minJaar) * rangewidth),0).release().perform();

// move upper handle
slider = getDriver().findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains (@class, 'facetapi-slider')]"));
maxhandle = slider.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains (@class, 'handle-max')]"));

SliderAction.clickAndHold(maxhandle).moveByOffset(-(int)((sliderMax - maxJaar) * rangewidth),0).release().perform();
```